# How to handle ruby file with jwt for applestore connect API

Tags: ruby, jwt, app-store-connect

I've been struggling to sign the jwt and I'm not familiar with the ruby file provided by apple on WWDC.. the code reads

```
require "base64"
require "jwt"

ISSUER_ID = "your-ID"
KEY_ID = "your-KeyID"

private_key = OpenSSL::PKey.read(File.read())

token = JWT.encode(
   {
    iss: ISSUER_ID,
    exp: Time.now.to_i + 20 * 60,
    aud: "appstoreconnect-v1"
   },
   private_key,
   "ES256",
   header_fields={
     kid: KEY_ID }
 )
puts token
```

The code keeps giving me this error when I run it on terminal:

[image]

my goal is simple, I just want to return some data from the GET api but am struggling with the 401 error on postman.

Comment: Is your ruby interpreter older than 1.9?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper no it's not. I have 2.6.3 on my terminal when I use ruby-v

Comment: Well, it looked like, ruby was confused by the "new" hash syntax (it's not really new, it's there since version 1.9). Otherwise, I can run the ruby script without getting the syntax error in `encode`. The HTTP code 401 means, you need to the set the "Authorization" request header properly - or you didn't sign the JWT properly (if you use this anywhere in the HTTP request).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper wow, what did I do wrong with the code, in that case? the keyID / issueID I'm using is the one issued by apple. I changed the values and ran the script via terminal but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code according to the screenshot you posted.

There's also what appears to be an error or misconfiguration in your code sample.

The gem most frequently used to encode/decode JWTs in ruby is [here](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt); this is the gem you're using in your example (via `require "jwt"`) There are a number of examples on that page you can reference, but if you look thru the README you'll note they mention you can only use a `kid` with `RSA` and you're not using `RSA` in your example.

Try this:

```rb
token = JWT.encode(
   {
    iss: ISSUER_ID,
    exp: Time.now.to_i + 20 * 60,
    aud: "appstoreconnect-v1"
   },
   private_key,
   "ES256"
)
```

Here's a link to [using a JWK](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt#json-web-key-jwk) with the `kid` and the `RSA` algorithm.

Search for `ecdsa_key` on that same page for examples with `ES256` (you'll find the one I posted above).

Seeing the original example from the WWDC docs might help provide additional context for the correct configuration but I'm not sure where to find that document. If it's public and you can link to it I can follow up.